# How to convert electron app into web app?

Tags: html, native, electron

I developed an Electron application few weeks ago with the framework AngularJS (used to make the client side).  I would like to convert this desktop application to a classic Web App.

Comment: did you tryed to do something?

Comment: did you find the answer?